# Excel Macro To Highlight Every Row Above Every Empty Row

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an excel data sheet which is divided into data blocks of variable number of rows. 
Data blocks are separated from each other with an empty row. 
What I am in a dire need for is a macro that highlights the last row of each data block; which is the row above the empty row.

Can I get some help with this request please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use Conditional Formatting. Put the cursor in the first cell of the column (I'm going to assume its A1 for this example). Create a Conditional Formatting rule with "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" with the following formula: **=IF(ISBLANK(OFFSET(A1,1,0)),TRUE,FALSE)**

[image]

Once the rule is created, right click, select Format Painter, and drag it down the column to apply that format to all relevant cells. If you apply the formatting rule to the entire column, the "Applies to" field should read **=$A:$A**

[image: Format Painter]

[image]

Comment: Thank you P Fitz for your answer. I have pasted the formula in a new rule, but it did not actually create any change; Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you set a particular format for the affected cells? Also, double check the "applies to"  field.

Comment: Yes, I set a particular format, and applied it to the entire sheet. I tested it on different sheets, and actually got the same result, no change has applied. I believe it is me missing something.

Comment: Now I know where my mistake was. I'm so grateful P Fitz. Thank you very much as it works as exactly as desired. All the best.